# Vuetify: remove color transition from v-icon

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, css-transitions, vuetify.js

I have a menu with menu items consisting of both icon and text, with hover color styled with css below:

```css
.v-list-item:hover {
    background: #0091DA;
}

.v-list-item:hover .v-list-item__title, .v-list-item:hover .v-icon {
    color: white;
}
```

The issue is text color changes instantly while icon color changes with a transition, and looks really strange.

**Question:** Can the transition on color change on `v-icon` be removed?

Please refer to example code below for the issue.

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  });

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = false
```

```css
.v-list-item:hover {
    background: #0091DA;
  }

  .v-list-item:hover .v-list-item__title, .v-list-item:hover .v-icon {
    color: white;
  }
```

```html
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  
  <div id="app">
    <v-app>
      <v-content>
      
        <v-list dense>
          <v-list-item>
            <v-list-item-icon class="mr-0">
              <v-icon small>mdi-message-text</v-icon>
            </v-list-item-icon>
            <v-list-item-title>Menu item 1</v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item>
          <v-list-item>
            <v-list-item-icon class="mr-0">
              <v-icon small>mdi-dialpad</v-icon>
            </v-list-item-icon>
            <v-list-item-title>Menu item 2</v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item>
          <v-list-item>
            <v-list-item-icon class="mr-0">
              <v-icon small>mdi-call-split</v-icon>
            </v-list-item-icon>
            <v-list-item-title>Menu item 3</v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item>
        </v-list>
        
      </v-content>
    </v-app>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `transition: none` to the icon seems to do the trick:

```css
.v-list-item .v-icon {
  transition: none !important;
}
```

Demo:

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  });

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = false
```

```css
.v-list-item:hover {
  background: #0091DA;
}

.v-list-item:hover .v-list-item__title, .v-list-item:hover .v-icon {
  color: white;
}
  
.v-list-item .v-icon {
  transition: none !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  
  <div id="app">
    <v-app>
      <v-main>

        <v-list dense>
          <v-list-item>
            <v-list-item-icon class="mr-0">
              <v-icon small>mdi-message-text</v-icon>
            </v-list-item-icon>
            <v-list-item-title>Menu item 1</v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item>

          <v-list-item>
            <v-list-item-icon class="mr-0">
              <v-icon small>mdi-dialpad</v-icon>
            </v-list-item-icon>
            <v-list-item-title>Menu item 2</v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item>

          <v-list-item>
            <v-list-item-icon class="mr-0">
              <v-icon small>mdi-call-split</v-icon>
            </v-list-item-icon>
            <v-list-item-title>Menu item 3</v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item>
        </v-list>
        
      </v-main>
    </v-app>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```